# For-Loop making code what optimizes over 7 constants inordinately slow

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, apply

I am trying to run a code that looks for the best predictive measures over 20 years of epidemiology data. I am optimizing the model over 7 constants, so I have code that looks like:

```
correcttot<-function(v,p,r){  
  correct3<-array(0,dim=c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10))
  for(i in 1:10){
    for(j in 1:10){
      for(k in 1:10){
        for(l in 1:10){ 
          for(m in 2:10){
            for(n in 2:10){
              for(o in 1:10){
                correct3[i,j,k,l,m,n,o]<-percentcorrect((i/10),(j/10),(20*k),(20*l),m,n,o,v,p,r)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
 print(correct3)
}
```

But this runs about as slow as molasses (takes about 35 hours). I know that apply() is a better option than for loops in many cases, but is there any way to use that in this case? What would that look like? The function (percentcorrect) takes seven constants, and then three vectors from my data set v,p,r. The function is not particularly fast, but still this takes a very, very long time.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: That is like 10 million calls of correct3. How long does one call take (or say 10)? `lapply` cannot do magic. There are only 86,400 seconds in a day.

Comment: One call takes about 7 seconds. So is this just a fools errand?

Comment: It should be taking a lot longer than 35 hours. 70 million seconds is 810 days, or 2.2 years. Must not be taking as long for certain parameters.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't keep running if the result is going to be NA or 0, which a lot of them will be. this is the readout for system.time on a single run               system.time(percentcorrect(.3,.4,40,100,10,5,4,v,s,p))
   user  system elapsed 
  5.141   0.028   5.241

Comment: If you post more code maybe we can help optimize. Or just mark geofurbs answer as correct (he needs the points) and optimize yourself.

Code reviews are best posted on the StackExchange forum of that name by the way.

Comment: What is the best way to go about getting help optimizing. I don't want to be a nuisance but I feel that I may be out of my depth.

Comment: You could post the code here and ask for help if it is not too long. Post an example of your data too, enough so that people can recreate it easilz. That is probably the easist thing to do. If it is longer I would post it in Code Review.

Comment: I think it may be too long, so I will try it in code review. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Here is a link to my code review query: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111509/trying-to-optimize-over-7-constants-function-takes-too-long-to-make-this-manage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running percentcorrect 10 million times. Do everything you can to speed that function up. If it's reading your vectors from disk, try to get all that in memory in advance. If they're printing something to console, kill any output.

Doing ANYTHING 10 million times takes a while.

PS:
You might consider other optimization method than brute-forcing every possible answer. Unless your results are completely random for each combination, there's gotta be a prettier way to do this. Linear optimization is a rich field.